# How to show more than one images within a circle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to show user profile photo with in a 60x60 circle. I can did this using a single photo. But I have faced  challenge while group profile's picture to show with in above mentioned circle. Here i need to show those pictures like collage.

Please anyone share your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: pls show your code

Comment: Not yet started in code structure. I am confusing how to start. Because i am retrieve images from database.  These images i need to put in the circle. Some time comes 3 images , some time comes 4 images. So i am confusing with dynamic photo count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put the images into an "circle"-div and set the overflow to hidden:

```css
.thumbnail{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.thumbnail>img{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/30x30">
</div>
```

**Edit**
add float: left to the images and removed one image

Comment: Ya , Fine. But in my case images count is in dynamic. Some cases only two images will come and another some cases more than two images will come. So how could achieve this.?

Comment: i would say, you have to do this via your backend andset the height and width of your img dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a front-end js question,putting it back-end is more reasonable. With different program language,there are different ways.

- Python:the images could understand as `ndarrays (numpy package)`,joining the images equals to joining the array.
- Java: `canvas.drawbitmap()` draw them together.

Comment: I am retrieving image's download url only from database side. So i cannot achieve this in back end.

Comment: Fine, if you are sure it is a front end problem, you could solve it by css. Put all the images in a `<div>` .Then design the relative positions by the image list size and put them into it.